# WP Gutenberg. Кастомное выделение текста

Tags: wordpress, gutenberg

Как в гутенберге сделать кастомное **выделение текста**?
Например, как выделение жирным или курсивом, только див с моим классом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте написать html код, это не так сложно. А где необходимо выделить пропишите `<span class="custom_bold">Текст</span>`

Comment: @ИванИпатов вопрос не об этом

Comment: Да, @KAGGDesign прав. В гутенберге тексты будут добавлять контенщики, а не я, поэтому нужно сделать для них отдельную кнопку.